# Wann spricht man „ie“ als Diphthong aus?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

„ie“ hat die folgende mögliche Aussprachen:

- /iː/ („Miete“)
- /i̯ə/ („Familie“, „Petersilie“)
- <s>/i̯e/ („Karriere“)</s>

Wie kann man wissen, ob „ie“ als Diphthong oder Monophthong ausgesprochen ist?

Comment: Man muss hier darauf achten, das [Diphthong](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) nicht mit dem [Hiat](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiat) zu verwechseln. Ein Diphthong hat man nur dann, wenn der Doppellaut innerhalb einer Silbe ist. Also, Mie-te, aber nicht Kar-ri-e-re.

Comment: dict.leo.org hat abhörbare Aussprachehilfen: http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Karriere

Comment: @Stefano Palazzo: Ist nicht *Miete* ein Monophthong, *Karriere* ein Diphthong, und *Antiestablishment* (blödes Beispiel) ein Hiat?

Comment: @Tim: How can you keep yourself always asking questions but still manage to make good ones? :D ahah Nice one +1

Comment: @Stefano: Ich glaube, dass das stimmt (in „Standard“-Aussprache). Ich habe das Beispiel gelöscht; hoffe das niemand vermisst es.

Comment: @Stefano Danke! Das in *Familie* ist dann also auch ein Diphthong, weil Familie nur drei Silben hat, ja?

Comment: Nein das i in Miete ist einfach ein lang gesprochenes i und das e wird geschrieben um die Länge anzuzeigen.

Comment: @Stefano _ie_ in _Miete_ ist ein Monophthong, weil der Vokallaut sich nicht verändert (/i:/), aber es ist mit zwei Vokalen geschrieben. _ie_ in _Familie_ ist aber ein Diphthong (/iə/).

Comment: Jap, so und nicht anders. I hab' leider oben das falsche Beispiel benutzt...

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo: In der Umgangssprache ausgesprochen wie "Kar-je-re", insofern ist die Auflistung schon gerechtfertigt.

Answer (score 9):

Ohne es zu wissen oder eine Regel zu kennen, kann ich mir die Herkunft als entscheidenden Faktor für die Aussprache vorstellen.

> Miete kommt direkt aus dem Deutschen (mittelhochdeutsch).
>
> Karriere kommt vom französischen carrière, mit minimal eingedeutschter Aussprache
>
> Familie kommt vom lateinischen familia, wo die Endung bereits aus zwei Lauten besteht.

Im besten Fall kennst du die Herkunft des Wortes (oder hast es schon einmal jemanden sagen gehört). Im schlechtesten Fall hilft nur das Wörterbuch.

Comment: Verlassen kann man sich leider nicht darauf. Es gibt z.B. bei Wörtern lateinischen Herkunft beide Varianten: Arie, Linie, Orgie - aber: Kopie, Manie, Galerie, ...

Comment: Arie: italienisch aria; Linie: mittelhochdeutsch linie, lateinisch linea; Orgie: Lateinisch orgia; Kopie: spätmittelhochdeutsch copī < mittellateinisch copia; Galerie: französisch galerie. Bei Manie versagt die Herkunft (lateinisch mania). Aber die Quote ist doch nicht so schlecht ;) Bleibt also dabei: am besten hat man es schon einmal gehört oder guckt ins Wörterbuch :)

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, man muss es auswendig lernen. Ich würde sagen, wenn man sich nicht sicher ist, spricht man es als Monophthong, also wie ein langes i, weil das der Regelfall ist. Die wichtigsten Ausnahmen hast Du schon selbst genannt.

Sicherlich gibt die Etymologie der Wörter auch Hinweise auf die Aussprache:

*Karriere* ist ein Lehnwort aus dem Französischen, daher sicherlich auch die Aussprache.

*Familie* kommt vom lateinischen "Familia" - auch hier eindeutig, dass es sich um zwei Vokale handelt, nicht um einen gedehnten.