# pronunciation of "ie"

Tags: pronunciation

The pronunciation for *ie* in *vier*[¹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vier#German) is a long *i* sound as in *Bier* (IPA: /biːɐ̯/), but for *vierzehn*[²](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vierzig) and *vierzig*[³](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vierzehn#German), it is shorter i-sound (IPA: /ˈfɪʁtseːn/ and /ˈfɪʁtsɪç/).

What are the rules for pronunciation of the *ie* sound in German?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German, the single letter *i* may be spoken as a short sound as in *mit*, or as a long sound as in *Stil*. You even have both versions in the word *Pazifik* (the first *i* is pronounced long, the second is short, without any obvious indication for that).

It is supposed to be a general rule, that *ie* is always spoken as a long sound, as you noticed in *Bier*. The examples of *vierzehn* and *vierzig* are the only counter examples i know.

Conversely, most long pronounced *i* sounds are writte as *ie*, but there is a much longer list of counter examples to that, so this is a rule of thumb at most.

Finally, there is no difference in pronunciation between *i* and *ie*, if the *i* sound is pronounced in its long version.

Comment: Hi,please don´t youse the word *Mitte* as an example for a short *i* in a word.
To pronounciate the *i* in *Mitte* short results of the double *t* after the *i*.
In German the letter in fromt of a double letter would always be spoken short.

Comment: I'd like to add that there **are** dialects in German where *vier* and *vierzehn* are actually pronounced alike in terms of the `ie`.

Comment: @FrankAus5419135 edited.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not so much the length (as a non-native speaker you can in case of doubt always resort to some intermediate length), but whether a special separation of *e* applies, as discussed in [this German question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/599/1696).

Rule of thumb: *ie* is mostly long. There is a noticable shortening of long *ie*s as in *spazieren* to participle *spaziert*, which results from loss of stress. For a definitive answer where the stress is, I see no alternative to a pronounciation dictionary.

Comment: *if two consonants follow,* ie *is pronounced short.* – Nope, if indicating a single vowel, *ie* is almost always pronounced long. *Vierzehn, vierzig,* and *Viertel* are exceptional. (In fact, I challenge you to find any other word with a short *ie.*)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: generally accepted, answer revised; not much difference to *siebzehn*, *siebzig* and *Siebtel* however.